# Note taking application for Android with option to share

Tags: android, note-taking

I am looking for a note/memo Android application that has the ability to share these notes from within the application.

What I am using now, only has the option to open, copy and delete if I long press it. I want a feature to send the notes e.g via Bluetooth etc. to a different device e.g. my Symbian device. Actually the notes application for Symbian has this feature.

I'm using Android 4.3.

Comment: Except for sharing, what features do you need? Should it be cloud based, or rather have no connection to any cloud? What about pricing? And while you're waiting for answers, you might wish to take a look at [my corresponding app-listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_notes) ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! I wanted a simple note taking app with no fancy features such as cloud,, strictly offline. Im already reviewing the apps you provided in the link. Very helpful

Comment: Perfect!! I just found the suitable application I have been loking for months! Please write an answer to this efect, Notepad is a perfect example of what I have been looking for

Comment: Oh – I just recommended a different one. "Notepad" is far too specific (<- ironically meant, as that's what almost every second app is named – so I cannot even tell which one you refer to) :-) Apart from that: Remember my lists for the next app-hunt, might save you the one or other month of "looking in vain" :D

Comment: PS: Be welcome to [add your own answer](/help/self-answer), might prove helpful to others!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Simple Notes](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.simplemobiletools.notes)** (also [available at Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplemobiletools.notes)) should be a perfect match for you:

[image: SimpleNotes] [image: SimpleNotes]
<sup>*Simple Notes* (source: [Github](https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Notes); click images for larger variants)</sup>

It seems to match your requirements, even those not explicitly named:

- possibility to share notes: Yes, see the share icon in the first screenshot
- simple: Yes, as the name suggests
- lightweight: the `.apk` is less than 1.5 MB
- free and libre, find it [at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.simplemobiletools.notes) and its source [at Github](https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Notes) (if you insist, you can also install [from Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplemobiletools.notes))
- no trackers, ads or other "PUS" (Potentially Unwanted Stuff)

For alternatives, as mentioned in my comment on your question, you can always consult my app listings – in this case the one for [notes apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_notes). There, if you're privacy aware, watch out to avoid (or at least do closely check) those entries with "monitoring icons" attached, which indicate trackers (analytics, ads etc.). Click those icons for details when investigating. Or better, only install from F-Droid :)

Enjoy!

Comment: This is also a perfect match